# Sharepoint 2010 - Event receiver ItemUpdated event doesn't get fired when scheduling is enabled

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When I manually changed the status of an item in a document library to "Approved", the event receiver's ItemUpdated event got fired. But when I enabled scheduling(to approve an item) to another item, the ItemUpdated event doesn't got triggered. Could anybody please help me on this issue.

Thanks
Sj